# Vue: My initial data value is not accessible when used as a function param

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am having an issue when triggering the click handler in my button here.  The error comes back as `TypeError: Cannot read property 'discountProduct' of null` when I click the button.  I know for a fact that `this.discountProduct.id` has a value by inspecting it from the Vue Tools and by knowing that the button is rendering to begin with since it only conditionally shows if the `id` > 1.
I alternatively tried to remove `this` but it still throws the same error.
I also tried manually just inserting the product id as the param and that works so I am not sure what the issue is at this point.

```
<button v-if="this.discountProduct.id >= 1"
    type="button"
    v-on:click="addToCart(this.discountProduct.id, true)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you button in the `<template>` tags?

If so, you do not need to use `this` delete from the click argument and v-if. However that should only throw a warning.

Can you also post the code for the method `addToCart`?

If you are not setting the full `discountProduct` object you will need to make sure setting the id is reactive. Like the example below:

```
this.$set(this.discountProduct, 'id', 1)
```

Nested Object/keys are not reactive without using $set. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html for more details.

Hope this helps